# How to install php-fpm-5.5 rpm with all dependencies installed at once

Tags: nginx, centos, rpm, vps, php

I'm running centos6 on a VPS. When I write the command,

```
# rpm -ivh ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-fpm-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpmrpm -ivh ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-fpm-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
```

The output is

```
# rpm -ivh ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-fpm-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
Retrieving ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-fpm-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.4-1.el6.remi is needed by php-fpm-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686
```

So I go for php-common to install

```
# rpm -Uvh ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
```

And it comes with these dependencies

```
Retrieving ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/remi/enterprise/6/test/i386/php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        php-pecl-jsonc(x86-32) is needed by php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-pecl-zip(x86-32) is needed by php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-cli-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-pdo-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-gd-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-fpm-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-xml-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
        php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi is needed by (installed) php-mbstring-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.i686
```

My question- is there any way to install them all at once? Sorry if I being so noob!

Comment: Have you heard of `yum`?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on yum argument, if you think yum might be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `yum`.

Based on the files I see in that directory, I am guessing it's a mirror of the "Remi" builds. I found them at http://rpms.famillecollet.com/ . For CentOS 6, simply install [their repo RPM](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm) and then `yum install php-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

rpm , the command-line tool, is very basic and doesn't work to fulfill dependencies.  You cannot effectively use it to install anything implicitly.

Where rpm will report missing dependencies and quit cleanly, a tool like yum or apt(for rpm) will try to satisfy those dependencies and implicitly add their providers to the install target.

In short, you're not using the best tool for the job you're doing.  Use yum or apt if you need it to just (mostly) do the right thing.